# Validate a coordinate if is inside a Polygon

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, coordinates

I have a table called Coordinates with 4 columns(Id,Longitude,Latitude,CityId) where Id is the PK, Longitude and Latitude are the coordinate and finally CityId is a FK with a table called Cities, in my Cities table i have 3 Cities, every city has a List of Coordinates, my question is how can i verify in which city is a Point(Latitude,Longitude), it means return the CityId of the city which belongs the point, Im using .Net Core,Entity FrameworkCore, I need a function that returns to me the cityId from a Point sent.
I have searched but anything I found is to verify if a point is into a Polygon, it returns a true or false, but in my case I have 3 polygons(for 3 Cities), so I don't need a bollean because I have 3 polygons, I need the City Id which the point belongs.
Some help will be appreciate, thanks advanced

[This is my Table Coordinates:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMIyW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `STIntersection` of the `geography` type in SQL Server (I presume you are using, based on the screenshot of SSMS). This will be good in SQL Server 2016+.

```
declare @g geography = 'POLYGON((-1 -1, 1 -1, 1 1, -1 1, -1 -1))'
declare @intersects geography = 'POINT(0 0)'
declare @notIntersects geography = 'POINT(-2 -2)'

select @g.STIntersection(@intersects).ToString(), 
       @g.STIntersection(@notIntersects).ToString()

(No column name)    (No column name)
POINT (0 0)         GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

You could query for all points associated with a `CityId` (they're in order, yes?), and construct a `geography` from them, then query for intersections. Alternatively, you could modify your schema to use `geography` with a polygon for the city points.

To use this functionality from EF Core, you'll need `geography` column types and use the data types from [Net Topology Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial).

Comment: Well, i started to read about NTS TopologySuit, my question is how to create a polygon from the list of coordinates from Database?
And i think this library has methods to know if a point is inside of the polygon previously created right ?